# parsing a .conf file in c

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, configuration-files, variable-assignment

Perhaps this bridge likely has been crossed many times and in many ways... reading a simple text .conf file and acting upon its entries.

In my case, the file format is simple.. a series of tokens and assignments, as in:

```
token_name_1    value
```

with a tab character as the field delimiter and a unix line-ending for each the record.

The .conf file directly alters certain program configurations, all of them stored in a single structure.  Variables of types Integer, float, char[], and *char are represented in the structure.

A quick but boring approach involves, for example:

```
if (strcasecmp(token,"token_name_1")==0)
    token_name_1=value;
```

But I determined that it would be sweet to do the deed in a nice tight loop.  In C.

So it seemed best to construct an array which provides pointers to each of the structure variables I wish to expose; another that provides the name of the variable; and a third which describes the stored data type and a desired default value.

These look like this:

```
const char* allowed_tokens[] =
{
    "loglevel",
    "debugecho",
    "errorSqlDisable",
    "ClearErrorDbOnExit",
    "\0"    // terminates list
}

int *varpointers[] =
{
    &appinfo.nLogLevel,
    &appinfo.debugEcho,
    &appinfo.OWFSLogLevel,
    &appinfo.OWFSLogEchoToDisplay,
    0   // terminates list
};

char *varDatatypes_defaults[] =
{
    "I|6",      // for LOG_INFO
    "B|false",
    "I|0",  
    "B|true",
    "\0"    // terminates list
};
```

The loop looks like this (pseudocode):

```
row=0;
while (read a line of the .conf file into cLine)
{
    get the token_name and value from cLine
    check if allowed_tokens[row]==0 and if true, exit the loop
    // example cLine= "debugecho    false"
    find match to "debugecho" in allowed_tokens.  This provides an offset into varpointers and varDatatypes.
    get the default data type and default value tokens from varDattypes_defaults[row]
    Do the assignment.  For example, if the data type=="I":
      *varpointers[row]=atoi(value);

    ++row;
}
```

This technique works fine, but there are two problems.

1. It would be preferable to combine the three arrays into a single array.  Is there a best practice here?
2. The array of pointers (varpointers[]) is defined as *int.  I did so as I want it to hold pointers.  However if the variable pointed to is not an integer data type, warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type is triggered.  Of course, char * and int * cannot be mixed... so how otherwise could this be done such that a single pointer array is used?

I realize I can do all this in c++.  This luxury is not an option at this point.

Comment: Dunno if you're familiar with YAML (http://www.yaml.org/), but it might be a nicer way to do standard config parsing.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine them into one array by structs, e.g.

```
typedef struct { char *token; void *var; char *defaults; } the_type;

the_type the_data[] = { { "loglevel",  (void*)&appinfo.nLogLevel, "I|6" },
                        { "debugecho", (void*)&appinfo.debugEcho, "B|false" }, 
                      ... 
                      };
```

The generic pointer type is `void *`. Your code has to ensure you use the correct type when actually writing to the variable being pointed to, e.g. `*(int*)the_data[0] = 42;`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an enumeration to specify the types so you don't have to parse a string. The values could be stored in an union.

```
typedef enum {
    BOOLEAN,
    INTEGER,
} type_t;

typedef union value {
    bool boolean;
    int integer;
} value_t;

typedef struct token {
    char *name;
    type_t type;
    value_t value;
} token_t;
```

Now you can define your defaults like so:

```
token_t data[] = {
    { "loglevel", INTEGER, { 6 } },
    { "debugecho", BOOLEAN, { false } },
    { "errorSqlDisable", INTEGER, { 0 } },
    { "ClearErrorDbOnExit", BOOLEAN, { true } },
    { 0 }
};
```

This will get pretty cumbersome if the number of configuration keys gets large. You might want to think about storing the configuration in a hash table or a tree.

Here is a short [example](http://ideone.com/1j7Ph) that seems to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. If we are talking about the same data type, use double pointers (you get an array of arrays)
2. Declare a struct holding your pointers, then use a pointer to your struct to work on.

For declaring a general pointer, you can use void instead of int. But then every time you have to cast the pointer to use it properly.